# Windows 8.1 - windows update doesn't work with outbound connections that don't match a rule, blocked

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-firewall, windows-8.1

I would like to ask for some support.
I've installed windows 8.1 just to check it a bit.
Within windows firewall i wanted to block all outbound connections which do not match a rule but windows update stopped working. If i restore to default rules it's fine again but as soon as i switch to block outbound it doesn't work. I thought the rules for windows update are part of the default hardened rules but it doesn't seem to be the case.
I created some rules that i found on some forums:
svchost with windows update service
svchost with BITS
svchost with task scheduler - not sure if this is needed
but unfortunately i still have the same issue.

Could you please help me what are the minimum rules to be created to run windows update?

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Hey Techie007,

Thanks for the feedback!
I'm not sure if this is a duplicate. The referred question and solution works well for windows 7. But on windows 8.1 it doesn't.
I tried the following:

1. Set back the firewall rules to the default
2. Run windows update - works
3. Block outbound connections which do not match a rule
4. Run windows update - doesn't work
5. Add custom allow rule for svchost.exe, Windows Update and BITS services
6. Windows update still doesn't work

Comment: I tried also to use Windows Firewall Control app. This tool has a feature to show the recently blocked connections. 
With default rules, outbound blocked, i got 4 blocked lines from svchost while running windows update.
When i add my custom rules (windows update, BITS) i got only one left. Unfortunately the app not able to tell me which service is blocked but only the PID.
I tried one by one to allow all the services with that PID but i still have the same line in the recently blocked list and windows update still doesn't work. Of course if i allow svchost, it works.

Comment: Hey Tibi, thanks for providing the extra information. You may want to edit this new info directly into the question.  If you get the PID, you can look it up in the Task Manager (right-click the column headers in Task Manager to add the PID column), maybe that'll get you closer?